# EXEC sp_executesql: No cross server join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to execute following statement with a clause to prevent cross server joins:

```
SET @Sql = N'
    SELECT TOP(1) @CodeID = CodeType
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.Field 
    WHERE Name = @SearchName'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,
    N'@SearchName NVARCHAR(256), @CodeID NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT',
    @SearchName, @CodeID OUTPUT
```

For EXEC I use this statement:

```
  SET @Sql = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(@Sql, '''', '''''') + ''')' + CASE WHEN @ServerName = @ThisServer THEN '' ELSE ' AT ' + @ServerName END
    EXEC ( @Sql )
```

How do I adapt my statement to work with `EXEC sp_executesql`?

Comment: FYI, your first statement will give arbitrary results, as you have a `TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY`. You should really be using a `ORDER BY` in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that the procedure name `EXEC` calls can be furnished via a variable. So that can be:

```
DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000) = N'sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @exec N'SELECT 1';
```

-- or

```
DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@db) 
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @exec N'SELECT 1';
```

-- or

```
DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@server) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(@db) 
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @exec N'SELECT 1';
```

In your case:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    SELECT TOP(1) @CodeID = CodeType
    FROM bla.Field 
    WHERE Name = @SearchName;';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000) = CASE
  WHEN @ServerName = @ThisServer THEN N''
  ELSE QUOTENAME(@ServerName) + N'.' END
  + QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @exec @Sql,
    N'@SearchName NVARCHAR(256), @CodeID NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT',
    @SearchName, @CodeID OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Something that so many people seem to miss, and instead go down the full dynamic route. Another one for your "Bad Habits" series maybe? "Unnecessary use of dynamic queries"

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, I kind of went the other way here: https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql